# How to run the C# class inside jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I've the authentication class written in C# which takes the username and password and return the authcode.

Can I integrate this to jmeter so that during run time If I provide username and password it would give the authcode which I need to send as header manager for api calls.

If that was written in JAVA then its quite straight forward but is there any alternative to run the C# class inside jmeter

Answer (score 6):

Take a look into following solutions:

1. If you can make an .exe file from your class you could use [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) to run it
2. [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) - for working with COM Automation components
3. [jni4net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jni4net/) - brigde between Java virtual machine and .NET Common Language Runtime

Given necessary .jars and .dlls are in JMeter CLASSPATH you should be able to invoke you C# class from i.e. [Beanshell Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) or similar JMeter Test Element

If your class is simple enough it might be a better idea to re-write your class in Java, the platforms are quite similar and it shouldn't be much overhead.

Comment: Yes , That is actually auth.exe which takes email id and password to return the authkey. So as per your recommendation I should use OS process sampler. I am using mac machine for creating and running the jmeter scripts. So you think it would be possible?

Comment: Thanks. I have written that in JAVA.

Answer (score 2):

i don't think you can use jmeter this way, you might have to convert your program web-based (i.e use of asp.net by integrating your c# code, web page may take input and pass it to c# code). once you have url of your application then you can use jmeter to create http request. web services,database,ftp,jms etc can also be tested through jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer to the cause of your delay lies in your question: "My API does a few database calls, it selects some data from one table, and returns it and manipulates it and inserts it into other tables." If you can prove that the slowdown is not related to this DB activity (maybe with a monitoring tool), then maybe jmeter C# integration overhead is causing the slowdown?

Comment: Provide a solution to the question please.